Accessing CouchDB database in python
I'm attempting to connect to a CouchDB database using the cloudant Python library.
My connection to couchdb is successful, and I can see all the databases listed when I call client.all_dbs(), but when I try to access it using client[db_name], it returns None. Here's the code I tried.
import urllib3
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter
from cloudant.client import CouchDB
import warnings
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def connect_to_db(db_name):

    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', urllib3.exceptions.SecurityWarning)

    pkcs12_filename = 'path_to_client03.p12'
    pkcs12_password = 'pkcs12_password'
    CERT = 'path_client.crt'
    KEY = 'path_client.key'

    adapter = Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename, pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)
    USERNAME = 'user'
    PASSWORD = 'password'

    try:
        client = CouchDB(USERNAME, PASSWORD, url='https://url', connect=True, cert=(CERT, KEY), adapter=adapter, partitioned=True)

        if not client.session():
            print("CONNEXION  : Failed to establish a session with CouchDB.")
            return None

        print('CONNEXION  : Client created successfully.')
        print("Available databases:", client.all_dbs())

        if db_name in client:
            my_database = client[db_name]
            print(f'CONNEXION  : Database "{db_name}" accessed successfully.')
            return my_database
        else:
            print(f'CONNEXION  : Database "{db_name}" not found.')
            return None

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'CONNEXION  : Error connecting to CouchDB: {e}')
        return None

test = connect_to_db('test_db')
print(test)

What I get as an output:
CONNEXION  : Client created successfully.
Available databases: ['_replicator', '_users', 'abir_test', 'production', ... , 'test_db', ...]
CONNEXION  : Database "test_db" not found.
None

The database test_db is listed in the output of client.all_dbs(), which confirms its existence.
The database name is correct
Tested with partitioned=True and partitioned=False: Neither option made a difference.
Attempted to Access Database Directly: Tried using client.get(db_name) instead of client[db_name], but it still returns None

I tried this:
# set up in Macbook couchdb
brew install couchdb
# setup password
sudo nano /opt/homewbrew/etc/couchdb/local.ini

# there under
[admins]
admin = "mypass3333"

# close and save
# start couchdb
brew services start couchdb

# open couchdb in the browser 'https://127.0.0.1:5984'
# with create new database button 
# created 'test_db' database (empty)

# create an conda environment for python
conda create --name couchdb
conda activate couchdb
# install python and cloudant
conda install -c conda-forge python ipython
pip install cloudant

# start ipython
ipython

And then in the ipython shell:
from cloudant import CouchDB
username = 'admin'
password = 'mypass3333'
url = 'https://127.0.0.1:5984'

client = CouchDB(username, password, url=url, connect=True)
client.all_dbs() 
## ['test_db']

db = client['test_db']
db
## {}

doc1 = {
    "_id": "example_doc",
    "type": "test",
    "name": "Test Document"
}
doc2 = {
    "_id": "example_doc1",
    "type": "test1",
    "name": "Test Document1"

# and then:
db.create_document(doc1)
db.create_document(doc2)

db

{'example_doc': {'_id': 'example_doc',
  'type': 'test',
  'name': 'Test Document',
  '_rev': '1-068f96f5970ab89cc43a42d3dd99802f'},
 'example_doc1': {'_id': 'example_doc1',
  'type': 'test1',
  'name': 'Test Document1',
  '_rev': '1-fef29905487dd21b3baa225af6e99a51'}}

'test_db' in client
## True => so the `in` operator is even already
## implemented...

Can you without the other packages also then connect to your database? And write to it?
the fact that it printed with your code:
CONNEXION  : Database "test_db" not found.

and returned None means that
your condition if db_name in client evaluated to False
therefore the else: branch was evaluated.
After connection you had even listed
Available databases: ['_replicator', '_users', 'abir_test', 'production', ... , 'test_db', ...]

This again is sign that your db_name did not contain 'test_db' ...

Yes you're right, but it still doesn't change the fact that client[db_name] returns None

Your function connect_to_db(db_name).
returned None, not your client[db_name].
What did you put as argument to your connect_to_db() call - did you check the argument?
